# Confused about exercise using jQuery's height() Method

Tags: jquery

The code that is confusing me is the exercise on page 347 (Cut, Copy, Paste):
http://javascriptbook.com/code/c07/

So the paragraph that has been appended to the unordered list gives the height of the div with an id="page".

For me (using Chrome), it returns 424px. 
However, when I add up the heights of the content areas of the individual elements, I can't seem to get to this number.
I get: 75px + 36px + 50px + 50px + 50px + 50px + 24px = 335px

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Post your code here, not just as a link to a web site.

Comment: Haven't looked at the code, but I suspect it has to do with padding and/or borders.

Answer (score 0):

`.height()` returns the content height without the element's border, padding or margins. But, the child elements margins, paddings and borders will make up the element's content height. So, the `#page` element's `.height()` would return the value that is equal to all children heights + their borders, paddings and margins.

Answer (score 0):

When manually measuring the inner elements, did you include their margin/padding into your calculation?

For example, if you have 5 elements with a height of 10px each and no margin or padding, the height of the container would be 50px.

However, if the 5 elements also have a margin of 5px, the height of the container would be 100px.

Comment: No, when calculating the heights of the individual elements, I did not include the padding/ border/ margin- I do understand where you are coming from now though. But even when I do include the padding/ border/ margin of the individual elements, I can't seem to get to 424px. I now get 125 + 36+ 62+ 62+ 62+ 62 +44 = 453 px, not 424px. I'm using Google's DevTools to get my results. Though, even DevTools gives the height of the div as 516px not 424px...

Comment: If you update your question with the relevant HTML, CSS and the JS you're trying to perform, it would be a lot easier to explain the behaviour.

Comment: The best way to measure the full height of an element including margins, paddings and borders, is to use `.outerHeight(true)`. I've created a small [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/42dv46av/3/) to illustrate how the inner element's full height affect the containers inner height (returned by `.height()`).